# How to request my services on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've deployed a PHP application with 2 services on Google App Engine: admin and api.

I use a configuration file to route the requests.

My problem is that I can't route requests to my services. Only to the default.

Here is the structure:

```
|-- admin
    |-- public
        |-- index.php
    |-- admin.yaml
|-- API
    |-- api
        |-- index.php
    |-- api.yaml
|-- dispatch.yaml
|-- index.php
```

dispatch.yaml:

```
dispatch: 
  # Send all api traffic to the API.
  - url: "*/API/api/*"
    service: api

  # Send all admin traffic to the admin.
  - url: "*/admin/public/*"
    service: admin
    
  # Default service serves simple hostname request.
  - url: "*/*"
    service: default
```

admin/admin.yaml:

```
runtime: php73
service: admin

handlers:
- url: /admin/public/.*
  script: /admin/public/index.php
```

API/api.yaml:

```
runtime: php73
service: api

handlers:
- url: /API/api/.*
  script: /API/api/index.php
```

index.php: `echo "Not found";`

admin/public/index.php: `echo "Welcome to admin service";`

API/api/index.php: `echo "Welcome to api service";`

When I send a request: `https://SERVICE_ID-dot-PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com` or `https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com` the response is the expected one: Not found.

But when I send a request: `https://SERVICE_ID-dot-PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com/API/api/` or `https://PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com/API/api/` the response is an `error code 500` instead of: `Welcome to api service`.

What is the problem ? Configuration ? Request urls ? Other ?

Comment: Can you also add the [logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/viewing-service-logs) from your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the yaml files:

new dispatch.yaml

```
dispatch: 
  # Send all api traffic to the API.
  - url: "SERVICE_ID-dot-PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com"
    service: api

  # Send all admin traffic to the admin.
  - url: "SERVICE_ID-dot-PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com"
    service: admin
    
  # Default service serves simple hostname request.
  - url: "PROJECT_ID.REGION_ID.r.appspot.com"
    service: default
```

new admin/admin.yaml:

```
runtime: php73
service: admin

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: /admin/public/index.php
```

new API/api.yaml:

```
runtime: php73
service: api

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: /API/api/index.php
```

No more routing problem.